# Mathematical symbols in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

It's the first time I use LaTeX and I am a little bit confused.

I want to make this text

```
to dic + dcj for all 1 <= i, j <= 3
```

looks like this one 
[image: text]

I found multiple lists of LaTeX symboles, like this [list](https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols), but I didn't found how to do it. I just identified the `\leq` symbole

```
dic + dcj for all 1 \leq i, j \leq 3
```

this worked for less or equal but I got errors in the compilation. For the ic,cj,i,j font I didn't found any solution. Can someone help me?

Comment: You need `... to $d_{ic} + d_{cj}$ for all $1 \leq i,j \leq 3$...`

Comment: Here's a suggestion: Read [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comment, for an absolute beginner, take some introductionary courses and work out each chapter.

To give a fast answer, you have to obeye, if you are setting normal text or mathematics.  Mathematics have to be announced, that LaTeX will change its behavior.  To typeset parts of mathematical formulae within normal text, use a dollar sign (`$`) in the input to mark the beginning of a formulae and also its end.  Here is a MWE for your question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
To type the formulae within the normal text, you have to use a dollar
sign in the input, as here: to $d_{ic} + d_{cj}$ for all $1 \leq i, j
\leq 3$.

To present it as a formulae of its own paragraph, you have to use a
different environment, of course.
\end{document}
```

This looks like this:

[image]